# Prove $\exists r,s\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $ar+ns=1\iff$ there exists an integer $b\ne 0$ such that $ab\equiv 1 \pmod n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

For this problem $a,b,n\in\Bbb{Z},n\ge 1$

> Prove that there exist integers $r,s$ such that $ar+ns=1$ if and only if there exists a non-zero
> integer $b$ such that $ab\equiv 1 \pmod n$

So far this is my proof:

$(\impliedby)$ Assume $\exists$ a non-zero integer b such that $ab\equiv 1\pmod n$ 
(Want to show there exists integers $r,s$ such that $ar+ns = 1$). 
By assumption, $n|ab-1\implies ab-1=ns$, where $s$ is an integer.

I am not sure what to do next I see that I can get the $1$ on the right hand side but how do I bring in $r$ in the equation.
Also because it is a biconditional proof I know I need to show the other way as well but I am stuck.

Comment: How to bring $r$ in:  take $r$ as $b$

Comment: Please use MathJax, not whatever it is you are using. [Here is a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Use `\pmod{n}` to get the parenthetical “mod n” with proper spacing.

Comment: Thank you, but now I am left with ar - 1 =ns which then can be written as ar-ns=1. I need for it to be positive. @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Thank you @ArturoMagidin I am new to this and just now getting the hang of it will try to use MathJAx in the future or LaTeX

Comment: @NaturalMathLover:  so take $s'=-s$